# Modifying login for an encrypted boot partition (GRUB)

Tags: boot, grub, encryption, disk-encryption

I followed [an tutorial on the archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#Encrypted_boot_partition_(GRUB)) for an encrypted boot partition and I have some questions. Up to now everything is working (two partitions: efi + encrypted lvm), and when booting I come to the following screen,

```
Welcome to GRUB!
Attempting to decrypt master key...
Enter passphrase for hd0,gpt2 (... long key ...): _
```

I wonder if its possible to reprogram this screen, since it is not really detailed. In particular, it is not possible to enter the key again (for disk encryption) once it was entered wrongly. It shows the following messages and goes into the grub rescue mode:

```
error: access denied. 
error: no such cryptodisk found.
error: disk "lvmid/..../..../" not found. 
Entering rescue mode ...
grub rescue> _
```

However, this grub rescue terminal seems to be very limited, it does not even support the command "help". Anyway, I would prefer to be able to type in the password again. It would also be nice to have more options, like loading the key from a storage of the local network, or using a fingerprint (I guess this is close to impossible). Further, I would like to change appearance etc. etc. Do you have ideas how to deal with this? It is clear that you can lay out a complete solution, but I would be happy to know where to start. I could not find any possibility when creating the config file for GRUB. I guess it would be necessary to fork GRUB for modifications like this?